# Git submodule pull overwrite/discard any local changes

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-pull

I have a submodule which I changed some local files. The original repository has been modified and I now wish to do a pull on the submodule, but I get an error saying that I will lose my changes.

How do I force git to ignore local changes and do the pull?

I know there are lot's of similar questions to this, but I couldn't find a question in stack overflow that answered my particular problem (specifically submodules).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git reset --hard` does exactly that - discard all changes and return to `HEAD`.

Or you can use `git stash` and after pull - `git stash apply` to restore your changes over updated tree.

If a submodule contains another submodules, it can be done recursively

```
# reset current directory
git reset --hard
# reset all submodules
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard
```

Comment: do you `git reset --hard` from inside the submodule directory or from the parent directory

Comment: `git reset --hard` discards all changes in the current repository. If done inside submodule it will discard changes in submodule. If outside -- submodule will be left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Change directory into the submodule then run this:

```
git checkout -f -b submodule-branch remotes/origin/submodule-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

git submodule update --remote --force pathToSubmodude

Answer (score -4):

I have a very silly solution, just clone all the files elsewhere, delete your local submodules, and put the new ones in.

Comment: I'll do that if I have to but I would rather not delete and re-add the submodule.